# What does replacing `vars` attribute by `groups` mean in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I run this bit of code in R. I have both dplyr and magrittr attached

```r
  agg <- landings %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(tot = sum(land, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% arrange(desc(tot))
```

and get the warning message

"Detecting old grouped_df format, replacing `vars` attribute by `groups` "

What does this mean?

Comment: Try `landings %>% ungroup %>% group_by(gear)`  (not clear without a reproducible example with `dput`), but I guess it would be some vestige of grouping attribute.  By `ungroup`ing you are remove the group info that existed and start with a new grouping attribute with `group_by`

Comment: @akrun that works. I guess the pre-processing (all dplyr stuff) that i did to the `landings` object gave it the class grouped_df. If i convert it to a data frame it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the group attributes.  If we `ungroup` and regroup the warnings would not be there

```
library(dplyr)
landings %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    group_by(gear)  %>%
    summarise(tot = sum(land, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(tot))
```

Or another option is to convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` and this would also remove the already existing attributes